# How to search in localstorage for specific word and get entire key and value?

Tags: javascript

On click i created localstorage item "storageKey__list" and value is "example.com"

I need to get all item keys and values ends with "__list" and then get entire key and value.

Result must be:
"storageKey__list , example.com"

Comment: This may help:  https://gist.github.com/n0m4dz/77f08d3de1b9115e905c

Comment: @Sid thank you for your time but it doesnot work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the entries in localStorage using `Object.entries()` and then use `.filter()` to obtain only the entires ending in `"__list"` by using `.endsWith()`:

```
Object.entries(localStorage).filter(([key]) => key.endsWith('__list'));
```

**Output:**

```
[["storageKey__list", "example.com"]]
```

A more browser friendly version of the code above could be to use the following:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /__list$/.test(key);
}).map(function(key) {
  return [key, localStorage.getItem(key)];
});
```

**Output:**

```
[["storageKey__list", "example.com"]]
```

Comment: Easy and simple solution, thank you for great answer and for your time <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
/** @type {[string, string][]} */
const keyValuePairs = [];

for (let i = 0, l = localStorage.length; i < l; i++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(i);
  if (key.endsWith("__list"))
    keyValuePairs.push([ key, localStorage.getItem(key) ]);
}

console.log(keyValuePairs);
```